# On Padoa's Method in the Theory of Definition: notation doubt

Tags: logic, notation, model-theory

In "On Padoa's Method in the Theory of Definition", written by Beth in 1953, I found a notation that is not really clear.

In particular, in the attached image, [image]

in the point (iii) of statement 2.4, I can't understand the formula Z.
What does D means? And what does (x)X(x) means?

Thank you.

Comment: Would it make sense in context for the $\sf D$ to be an indexed disjunction?

Comment: $(x_m)X_p(x_m)$ might be old-fashioned notation for $\forall x_m :  X_p(x_m)$, since the captial $X$s otherwise look like they behave like predicates.